# How to use key words to form a meaningful sentence?

Tags: nlp, nlg

I am building a model that takes a few keywords such as "I" "drink" "water" and convert it into a meaningful sentence such as "I am drinking water". Is there any reference or a way by which I could do it?

Comment: This is called text generation. You would need a lot of things to generate text and it is not that straight forward. 
Check this [link](https://medium.com/phrasee/neural-text-generation-generating-text-using-conditional-language-models-a37b69c7cd4b). You need to read other articles also.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for methods of [*realization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_(linguistics)) as part of *natural language generation* (NLG). The best NLG systems are commercial but some Open Source systems exist, as also listed in the Wikipedia article. I found two maintained software libraries:

- [SimpleNLG](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg)
- [OpenCCG](https://github.com/OpenCCG/openccg)

And two projects that seem not to be maintained actively anymore:

- [KPML](http://www.fb10.uni-bremen.de/anglistik/langpro/kpml/README.html)
- [FUF/SURGE](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~elhadad/surge)

OpenCCG seems to provide more features than SimpleNLG but the latter seems easier to use. [This small example](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg/wiki/Section-V-%E2%80%93-Generating-a-simple-sentence) from the SimpleNLG tutorial may already be enough for your use case:

```java
 import simplenlg.framework.*;
 import simplenlg.lexicon.*;
 import simplenlg.realiser.english.*;
 import simplenlg.phrasespec.*;
 import simplenlg.features.*;

 Lexicon lexicon = Lexicon.getDefaultLexicon();
 NLGFactory nlgFactory = new NLGFactory(lexicon);
 Realiser realiser = new Realiser(lexicon);

 SPhraseSpec p = nlgFactory.createClause();
 p.setSubject("Mary");
 p.setVerb("chase");
 p.setObject("the monkey");

 // prints "Mary chases the monkey.":
 System.out.println(realiser.realiseSentence(p));
```

If you prefer Python [this wrapper around SimpleNLG](https://github.com/roman-kutlak/nlglib) may help.